# Encode special characters in XML for Universal Windows Platform app

Tags: c#, xml, win-universal-app

The recommended [System.Security.SecureElement.Escape()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(v=vs.110).aspx) method doesn't seem to be available for Universal Windows Platform applications.

What's the recommended way to convert a string (say `Wet Paint & Co`) to its XML-safe form (`Wet Paint &amp; Co`)?

Comment: Recommended by whom and for what? You don't need that method to generate escaped characters. Special characters should have been escaped when you actually generated the XML text. How *did* you generate the XML text? Both XmlElement.InnerText and the XElement constructor escape the provided text

Comment: The current code uses a StringBuilder (more flexible since we might switch to a binary format) but I am considering switching to use XElement instead. This issue only occurs in 2 places, so SecureElement.Escape() would have been ideal.

Comment: @stuartd I looked at that page, but this is for a UWP, so some of the options (including SecureElement.Escape()) are not available (UrlEncode add %20 and %26 instead of space and &amp;).

Comment: If you are looking for an alternative to StringBuilder, I would suggest using XElement, I can post an example of generating a safe Xml document from source code using XElement and XAttribute classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you look under [remarks in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securityelement.escape(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1), you can find a table with all characters which will be escaped from `SecurityElement.Escape`. The easiest way would be replacing these characters in your own method:

```
public static string Escape(string str){
    return str.Replace("&", "&amp;")
              .Replace(">", "&gt;")
              .Replace("\"", "&quot;")
              .Replace("\'", "&apos;")
              .Replace("<", "&lt;");
}
```

But this is pretty slow because each `Replace` will create a new string instance. For large strings it could be better to iterate over the string and add the characters to a `StringBuilder`.

```
public static string Escape(string str)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var chr in str)
    {
        switch (chr)
        {
            case '&':
                sb.Append("&amp;");
                break;
            case '<':
                sb.Append("&lt;");
                break;
            case '>':
                sb.Append("&gt;");
                break;
            case '"':
                sb.Append("&quot;");
                break;
            case '\'':
                sb.Append("&apos;");
                break;
            default:
                sb.Append(chr);
                break;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

*Yet I read that you build your XML with a `StringBuilder` so you can modify my `Replace` method and pass your `StringBuilder` to it. So it is not necessary to create a second instance.*

But in the most ways it is not necessary to encode a string yourself because classes like `XElement` etc. do it for you. As others said in the comments of your question I think too it is easier to use LinQ to XML (`XElement`, ...) or XML serialization to generate the XML.

Just for completeness